# Every element in $SU(2)$ has the form $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha& \beta\\ -\bar{\beta} & -\bar{\alpha}\end{bmatrix}$ with $\alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to prove that every element in $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ has the form 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \alpha& \beta\\ -\bar{\beta} & -\bar{\alpha}\end{bmatrix},
$$ 
with $\alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{C}$, for this I took an arbitrary element 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \alpha& \beta\\ \gamma & \delta\end{bmatrix},
$$ 
and I arrive at the following equalities 
$$
\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma=1, \quad \alpha\bar{\alpha}+\beta\bar{\beta}=1, \quad \bar{\alpha}\gamma+\bar{\beta}\delta=0, \quad \gamma\bar{\gamma}+\delta\bar{\delta}=1
$$

but I don't know from here how to prove that $\gamma=-\bar{\beta}$ and $\delta=-\bar{\alpha}$, any idea? Thank you.

Comment: the lower right element should not have a negative sign: $ \begin{bmatrix} \alpha& \beta\\ -\bar{\beta} & \bar{\alpha}\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the last equation by $\bar{\alpha}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\bar{\alpha} \gamma\bar{\gamma}+ \bar{\alpha} \delta\bar{\delta}=\bar{\alpha}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use the third equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
-\bar{\beta} \delta\bar{\gamma}+ \bar{\alpha} \delta\bar{\delta}=\bar{\alpha} \\
\delta( -\bar{\beta} \bar{\gamma}+ \bar{\alpha} \bar{\delta})=\bar{\alpha} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use the first equation and we have $\delta=-\bar{\alpha}$. The other equation can be derived similarly.

Comment: do we get $\delta=-\bar{\alpha}$ or $\delta=\bar{\alpha}$? according to what you did we should have $\delta=\bar{\alpha}$

Comment: $-\bar{\beta} \bar{\gamma}+ \bar{\alpha} \bar{\delta}=-1$

Comment: why? $\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma=1\Leftrightarrow \bar{\alpha}\bar{\delta}-\bar{\beta}\bar{\gamma}=\overline{\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma}=\bar{1}=1$?

Comment: That's right...

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$
 \bar{\alpha}\gamma + \bar{\beta}\delta = 0,
$$

it follows that

\begin{align*}
0 & = \alpha\bar{\alpha}\gamma + \alpha\bar{\beta}\delta \\
& = \left|\alpha\right|^{2}\gamma + \bar{\beta}(\alpha \delta) \\
& = \left|\alpha\right|^{2}\gamma + \bar{\beta}(1 + \beta \gamma )\\
&  = \left|\alpha\right|^{2}\gamma + \bar{\beta} + \left|\beta\right|^{2}\gamma \\
& = \gamma(\left|\alpha\right|^{2} + \left|\beta\right|^{2}) + \bar{\beta} \\
& = \bar{\beta} + \gamma,
\end{align*}

and so $\gamma = - \bar{\beta}$. The other question is derived similarly